# How to return null for custom function used in %dopar%?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I want to return NULL with a custom function used in a parallel `foreach` loop. The usage is that, if some result does not fulfill certain criteria, that result won't get stored and it'll get filtered out as a postprocess step.

However, my program returns

> task 1 failed - "replacement has length zero"

The problem can be reproduced with following code:

```
 library(doParallel)
 Input <- c(F,T,F)
 f.parallel <- function(x){
   ifelse(x,T,NULL)
 }
 no_cores <- detectCores()-1
   # for mac OS, linux
 c1 <- makeCluster(no_cores,type = "FORK")
   # for windows
   #   cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
   #   clusterExport(cl, list("Input","f.parallel"))
 registerDoParallel(cl)
 output <- foreach(i=1:length(Input),.combine = cbind) %dopar% f.parallel(Input[i])

 stopCluster(c1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `f.parallel <- function(x) if(x) TRUE`. `ifelse()` won't allow you to return `NULL`.

When `cbind()` is called to combine the results of your loop, the `NULL` elements will be removed. If you'd like to filter them out in a post-process step, I'd recommend using `ifelse(x, TRUE, NA)`.

Comment: it works with ```if(x) T```.  but i think ifelse() can return NULL. but it just does not work with %dopar%. if i change to %do%, it then works. but why is that so?

Comment: That's strange. Neither %do% nor `ifelse(TRUE, NULL, 1)` works for me.

Comment: maybe different versions? do you know how to pass column name to the value in custom function?

Comment: I'm using R 3.3.2. Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, so I'm guessing I don't know how to do it.

Comment: that's all right. thanks. the current solution is sufficient.

Comment: @coletl's explanation is correct. This has nothing to do with foreach per se; the error occurs when calling `f.parallel(Input[1])`.